# can i use two differnet variavbles in single this.state?

Tags: react-native, state

I have two variables which i have to pass into "this.state" so that i can use 2 different state variables into two functionalities.

for example:
this state:{ data:'abc'},{series:100}

series: this.state.series
data:this.state.data

can someone help me how to sort it out!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Feel free to mark your post as solved if the answer helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
this.setState({ data: 'abc', series: 100 })
```

then, you can get it with:

```
this.state.series
this.state.data
```

or in a cleaner way:

```
const { series, data } = this.state
```

Comment: Hi sir, I tried the solution suggested by you but am getting an error "Type Error: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.series').can you pls let me know y i am getting this error.  TIA

Comment: Please provide some code, I can't help you without seeing more of it.

Comment: constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.setState({ data: 1000, val: 1000/100 })
}
render() {
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
<View>
<Pie
radius={100}
innerRadius={90}
series={[this.state.val]}
colors={['#f00']}
backgroundColor='#ddd' />
<View style={styles.gauge}>
<Text style={styles.gaugeText}>Target : 100</Text>
<Text style={styles.gaugeText}>StepsTaken : {this.state.data}</Text>
</View>
</View>
</View>

Comment: Please edit you first message or provide some readable code. not in comments